# Count the length of head movement

Tags: code-golf, parsing, path-finding

Once upon a time I wanted to order custom tokens for a board game. They say they can do it, and then they present me their price list. I was confused because they charge per inch of head movement, and I have no idea how much will my tokens cost.

**INPUT:** a 2d grid:

- `|`,`-`,`\`,`/` are straight cuts. Each has a length of 1.
- `┌`,`┐`,`└`,`┘` are 90 degree corner cuts. Each has length of 1.\$^1\$
- `#`,`@` are 45 and 135 degree corner cuts respectively. Each has a length of 1.20.
- `+`,`X` are perpendicularly intersecting cuts. Each has a length of 1.
- `>`,`v`,`<`,`^` are the cut ends. Each has a length of:

  - 1.50, if the arrow points at the diagonal cut,
  - 1, if the arrow points at the beginning of next cut,
  - 0.50 otherwise.
- ABC...**UVWYZ**abc...xyz are the cut start points given in that order. They have a length of:

  - 0.50, if no other already made cuts are neighboring them,
  - 1.50, if if the cut begins next to the diagonal cut,
  - 1 otherwise.

**OUTPUT:** Distance that a head will move with up to 2 significant digits.

Assume that:

- The company doesn't count distance from resting position to starting point of the first cut,
- Each cut is made only once (intersections cut twice on the same character),
- All grids are valid,
- The head moves from the end of a cut to the beginning of another cut in a straight line.

Obviously no [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default), and the shortest code in each language wins!

**TEST CASES:**

Output: 0

```
A> B>
```

Output: 4

```
A------v
^------B
```

Output: 16

```
A┌┐^
└┘└┘
```

Output: 7.5

```
#B┐
|\v
A<#
```

Output: 11.4
*(Note: First the head cuts bottom-left triangle, then moves its head to the beginning of top-right triangle cut. 45 degree corners take continuations first instead of new cuts.)*

```
A-@<--┐
^  \  |
└--B@-┘
```

Output: 21.15

```
A-┐ ┌--┐ ┌-┐ ┌--┐ C-┐ ┌--┐ ┌-┐ ┌--┐
^ | |  | | | |  | ^ | |  | | | |  |
└-+-+--┘ └-+-+--┘ └-+-+--┘ └-+-+--┘
  | |      B |      | |      D |   
  └-┘      ^-┘      └-┘      ^-┘
```

Output: 138.41

```
 #-#
A X
 X \
@ @-#
v
```

Output: 13.5

```
A> F> K> P> U> a>
B> G> L> Q> V> b>
C> H> M> R> W> c>
D> I> N> S> Y> d>
E> J> O> T> Z> e┐
<---------------┘
```

Output: 104.29

\$^1\$ If needed, replace this with a set of your choice.

Comment: Can we use swap the 4 90 degree cut symbols for ASCII symbols (e.g. use 1,2,3,4) instead?

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "next to a diagonal cut". I thought it'd mean adjacent to `#` or `@` (since 45° and 135° lines are diagonals), but this doesn't fit with the test cases.

Comment: The output is defined as the distance that the head moves, but there's almost
no explanation of how the head moves. Each character is associated with a
"value"; are those actually distances? "The head moves from the end of the
first cut to the beginning of the second cut in a straight line"; is that
specific to the first cut, or true for all pairs of consecutive cuts?